# Reference section/Bibliography is not lining up correctly

Tags: bibliographies, formatting

I have written an IEEE style report with several references at the end and am finding that the references do not line up correctly.  I set

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
```

as the configuration for my references, but when calling `\bibliography{references.bib}`, find that the reference section is misaligned (see screenshot below).

[image: After reference #2 the alignment is incorrect]

Any idea how to get the references to align properly?

**EDIT**

At the request of @AboAmmar I have added an MWE which reproduces the error:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{pgf,pgfarrows,pgfnodes,pgfautomata,pgfheaps}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}

 \begin{document}
\cite{Jeong2021VehicularCommunications}
\cite{A.D.Angelica2016GooglesKurzweil}
\cite{KatoPropagationCommunications}
\cite{BianReducingCommunication}
\cite{Luo2006ACommunications}
\bibliography{references.bib}

\end{document}
```

A second screenshot is provided below to show the output:

[image: References 4 and 5 are out of alignment]

What's strange is that reordering the references sometimes makes the output look as expected.

Comment: Welcome! Please provide a MWE, a small portion of code that shows your issue for others here to copy-paste and reproduce. This way, you may get the best advice for your problem.

Comment: @AboAmmar Sure thing! I will make an edit to my question now!

Comment: Can you give the bib entries for Bian et al 2019 (`[2]` in the first screenshot) and Kato et al 2001 (`[3]` in the second screenshot)? They appear to be problematic.